# How to use the same eloquent query twice, but with one different where clause?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, reusability

I have this query:

```
User::leftJoin('friends', function ($join) {
    $join->on('friends.user_id_1', '=', 'users.id')
        ->orOn('friends.user_id_2', '=', 'users.id');
})
->where(function ($query) use ($myID) {
    // Group orwhere functions so the query builder knows these belong together
    $query->where([
        'friends.user_id_1' => $myID,
        'friends.accepted' => true
    ])
    ->orWhere([
        'friends.user_id_2' => $myID,
        'friends.accepted' => true
    ]);
})
->where('users.id', '!=', $myID) // Exclude the user with id $myID
->get();
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41832867/5437864

I want to use this query twice, but with a different where clause. Is it possible to reuse this query without copying the whole code? And if so, how?

Comment: yes, yes it is.

Comment: @nogad Thank you, but how? :)

Comment: Please, include at least part of the link content in your post, otherwise a link can be unnaccesable with the time and the question will get not understandable

Answer (score 1):

I used the PHP clone `keyword`. I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but it helps. Any other suggestions are welcome.

```
$friends_query = User::leftJoin('friends', function ($join) {
    $join->on('friends.user_id_1', '=', 'users.id')
        ->orOn('friends.user_id_2', '=', 'users.id');
})
->where(function ($query) use ($myID) {
    // Group orwhere functions so the query builder knows these belong together
    $query->where([
        'friends.user_id_1' => $myID,
        'friends.accepted' => true
    ])
    ->orWhere([
        'friends.user_id_2' => $myID,
        'friends.accepted' => true
    ]);
});

$friends_me = clone $friends_query;
$friends_me = $friends_me->where('users.id', '!=', $myID);

$friends_others = clone $friends_query;
$friends_others = $friends_others->where('users.id', '=', $myID);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = User::leftJoin('friends', function ($join) {
    $join->on('friends.user_id_1', '=', 'users.id')
        ->orOn('friends.user_id_2', '=', 'users.id');
})
->where(function ($query) use ($myID) {
    // Group orwhere functions so the query builder knows these belong together
    $query->where([
        'friends.user_id_1' => $myID,
        'friends.accepted' => true
    ])
    ->orWhere([
        'friends.user_id_2' => $myID,
        'friends.accepted' => true
    ]);
});
```

**Adding extra where to existing query**

```
$query->where('users.id', '!=', $myID)


$query->get();
```

Check this link for another example

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180169/laravel-how-to-add-where-clause-using-query-builder)

Comment: It's not working. The other link is using query builder.

Comment: It does not give any errors, but it applies 2 filters to the same query instead of one filter per copy. I used the `clone` keyword (see my answer).

Comment: I don't understand you, actually, what do you mean. But, you did same thing, with more long way.  There is not any 2 filters. You can every time add some conditions to the main `$query` which I provided.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this solution does not give the expected result. Otherwise I would have upvoted it.

Comment: May be it is not expected result for you, but you haven't provided more information, what do you want to do, actually. Your question wasn't so understandable.